# determine lower and higher value within a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
 pair_id group_id value
 <int>    <int>   <dbl>
    1        1    0.600
    1        2    0.400
    2        3    0.500
    2        4    0.500
    3        5    0.200
    3        6    0.800
    4        7    0.300
    4        8    0.700
    5        9    0.500
    5       10    0.500
```

It is generated with the following code snippet:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(pair_id = rep(1:5, each = 2),
             group_id = seq(1:10),
             value = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5))
```

My goal is to determine which group_id within each pair_id has a higher value and which has a lower value. Once determined, I want to assign "higher" to the group_id with higher value and "lower" to the group_id with lower value.

However, the caveat is that if two groups have an equal value (e.g. both have a value of 0.5, as in pair 2 and pair 5 in the example), the assignment of "higher" or "lower" should be determined at random.

The goal is to produce a dataframe with a new column, let us say group_rank, which should look like this:

```
pair_id group_id value group_rank
 <int>    <int> <dbl>  <chr>     
  1        1    0.600  higher    
  1        2    0.400  lower     
  2        3    0.500  higher    
  2        4    0.500  lower     
  3        6    0.800  higher    
  3        5    0.200  lower     
  4        8    0.700  higher    
  4        7    0.300  lower     
  5        9    0.500  lower     
  5       10    0.500  higher
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this within the tidyverse framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'pair_id', use `which.min` and `which.max` on the 'value' column to get the row index for subsetting the corresponding 'group_id'

```
df %>% 
  group_by(pair_id) %>% 
  summarise(groupMin = group_id[which.min(value)], groupMax = group_id[which.max(value)])
```

NOTE: If there are multiple `min` or `max` value for a 'pair_id', the `which.min` or `which.max` only get the first index

---

If there are multiple `min` or `max` value, then use the `==` and with `sample` get the `random` 'group_id'

```
df %>%
   group_by(pair_id) %>%
   summarise(groupMin = sample(group_id[value == min(value)], 1),
             groupMax = sample(group_id[value == max(value)], 1) )
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, we `arrange` by 'pair_id' and 'value' in descending order, grouped by 'pair_id', if the number of distinct elements in 'value' is equal to 1, then assign the "higher", "lower" values by `sample`ing or `else` assign it in the order of "higher" followed by "lower"

```
df %>% 
   arrange(pair_id, desc(value)) %>% 
   group_by(pair_id) %>% 
   mutate(group_rank = case_when(n_distinct(value) == 1  ~ sample(c("higher", "lower")),
          TRUE ~ c("higher", "lower")))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups: pair_id [5]
#   pair_id group_id value group_rank
#     <int>    <int> <dbl> <chr>     
# 1       1        1 0.600 higher    
# 2       1        2 0.400 lower     
# 3       2        3 0.500 higher    
# 4       2        4 0.500 lower     
# 5       3        6 0.800 higher    
# 6       3        5 0.200 lower     
# 7       4        8 0.700 higher    
# 8       4        7 0.300 lower     
# 9       5        9 0.500 lower     
#10       5       10 0.500 higher
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I updated my question, as it seems that it may be a bit unclear.  I added a target dataframe to illustrate my goal. The final goal is to produce a dataframe with "higher" or "lower" as a function of the set requirements. Basically, I'm looking for a way to assign these these categories right away. I want the random assignment of "higher" or "lower" only in pairs which have the same value, e.g. where min == max. In all other cases I want the assignment to be based on whether the value is max or min.

Comment: @HristoHristov  Updated the post

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!